# Sliding an edge distorts texture image (blender 2.81)

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

When I use loop cut/slide (with "Correct UVs" checked (!)) and move edge - texture image distorts. Even when I move it with "Edge Slide" (Ctrl+E). Also I tried "G, G". Nothing of these works. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Before updating to 2.81 version everything was OK.

Thanks.

Screenshot examples. Before and after.

[image: screenshot-example]

[image: screenshot-example]

Download .blend file:
https://www.upload.ee/files/10846777/texture-distort.blend.html

Comment: It could possibly be distorting the UVs when it tries to correct it.

Comment: Could you provide the .blend?

Comment: Yes. Here is link to download: https://www.upload.ee/files/10846777/texture-distort.blend.html

Comment: It is a bit different. Just removed objects from scene.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll try my best to fix this.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Generally best to recommend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for people to upload files to.

Comment: @RayMairlot k, thanks ;)